# Change android colorPrimary (app bar) to gradient color

Tags: java, android, xml, gradient

I need to change color on my application bar to some gradient color. I created action_bar_bg.xml file in drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:endColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

and I tried to change colorPrimary in styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <item name="colorPrimary">@drawable/action_bar_bg</item>

</style>
```

but it doesn't work. I am getting error: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/action_bar_bg.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f020046)`
I want to achieve that result:
[image: app bar with gradient]

What do I have to change in code?

Comment: `colorPrimary` expects actually a color, not a shape. You can add a `Toolbar` to your layout yourself and set the background there manually

Answer (score 2):

try on this way.
There's a new attribute called colorPrimary which you can define in your Theme. This will give you ActionBar or Toolbar a solid color.

Following a little example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_action_bar_color</item>
</style>
```

Please note: It has to be only colorPrimary, not android:colorPrimary, in every values-folder except the values-v21 one.

You can read more about customizing the Color Palette on [Android](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/material/compatibility.html#SupportLib)

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your onCreate in your Activity

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
Drawable gradient = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.action_bar_bg);
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(gradient);
```